# magento1.6.2 Invalid package name, allowed: [a-zA-Z0-9_-] chars

Tags: magento

I have installed Magento 1.6.2 and I am trying to install paid extension using “Direct Package file Upload”.
I use Magento connect manager 1.5.0
(I installed free extensions with extension key, It worked.)

Then I tried uploading one of the paid extensions I purchased using “Direct Package file Upload” and got the following error
CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
Invalid package name, allowed: [a-zA-Z0-9_-] chars
Invalid version, should be like: x.x.x
Invalid stability
Invalid date, should be YYYY-DD-MM
Invalid channel URL
Empty authors section
Empty package contents section

With another plugin I got:
File upload problem
or

CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
Invalid channel URL

Appreciate if anyone has resolved this issue before.

Thanks

Comment: you should contact the paid package vendor to solve this.

Comment: its happening with 4 or 5 plugins... I suspect this comes from magento. I'll contact them, they will probably help me.

Comment: I installed them manually and it worked.